# I wish you had cooked the supper

Tags: grammar, wish

It is past seven in the evening. But John has not cooked the supper yet. His wife is hungry. She says unhappily, "I wish you had cooked the supper."

Is it right to say "I wish you had cooked the supper"?

I know I can use this sentence for the past. Suppose John did not cook the supper yesterday; instead, they ordered a takeout. This morning, his wife could say "I wish you had cooked the supper [yesterday]."

Comment: What exactly are you asking? Of course the wife can say *I wish you had cooked the supper*. Without a full context, we don't know if she's talking about this evening, last night, or perhaps some special occasion many years in the past when John could have but didn't cook supper. But she could easily *force*  the "by now, this evening" sense by *I wish you had **already** cooked supper* if she was worried that John might be too stupid to understand her otherwise.

Comment: If she wants to urge him to get on with it, she would say "I wish you _would cook_ the supper."

Comment: Both the pluperfect and the definite article contribute to an interpretation that she's not talking about tonight's supper but some other one (and that he will know which one she's talking about).

Comment: I'm talking about tonight's supper. I'm asking whether she can use the sentence I wrote?